# Is possible to set the command line line (not prompt) from another program?

Tags: bash, command-line

I hope that this question won't be too ambiguous.

I would like to achieve following thing.

```
[user@host]# ./my_program SET THIS AS NEXT COMMAND THAT YOU CAN EDIT
[user@host]# SET THIS AS NEXT COMMAND THAT YOU CAN EDIT
```

Is there any way of achieving it without writing explicitly to a file descriptor?

I have a working shell, let's say with PID `10150`.
My current solution is following:

Console 1:

```
[user@host]# echo $$
10150
[user@host]#
```

Console 2:

```
[user@host]# echo -n "SET THIS AS NEXT COMMAND THAT YOU CAN EDIT" > /proc/10150/fd/0
[user@host]#
```

Console 1:

```
[user@host]# echo $$
10150
[user@host]# SET THIS AS NEXT COMMAND THAT YOU CAN EDIT
```